# Object Mapping to a Bitmap

Tags: c#, bitmap, mapping

I am writing a simple mapper class to clone and copy properties between different objects of different/same types.

Mapping is performed via reflection and works just fine for value types, lists and reference types.

Everything works for types like this one:

```
class SimpleValueTypes 
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Number { get; set; }
    public long LongNumber { get; set; }
    public float FloatNumber { get; set; }
    public bool BooleanValue { get; set; }
    public AnotherType AnotherProperty{ get; set; }
```

}

where AnotherType is a class type. Mapping of reference types is performed by inspecting the properties recursively until all the properties are mapped to the destination pretty much this way:

```
object value = mapFrom.GetValue(input, null);                
mapTo.SetValue(output, value, null);
```

where mapForm and mapTo are PropertyInfo objects.

Problems began when a new type with a "Bitmap" property arrived and I realised a whole class of objects cannot be treated the same way.

```
Class NewType
{
    public Bitmap Bitmap{get;set;}
    public string Name{get;set;}
}
```

What would you reccomend to do for cases like these? Obviously copying the properties would not lead to a new copy of the original Bitmap object.

PS

I can't use automapper/emit mapper or any other external packages.

Comment: why you can't use for example Automapper?

Comment: it's a policy for this project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are implementing a mapper and not use some existing ones :

I think that this always worked on your side, it's only a case of your project (which is a good news). The thing is that, by me, you arrived on point where you need to implement custom mapper.  So define some base class like `BaseMapper` with mapping basic functionality, and derive from it `BitmapMapper:BaseMapper` class which takes care of mapping of `Bitmap` type objects.

After a while could be you will get some other type, you will create `MyTypeMapper : BaseMapper` with concrete implementation of mapping.

This just a basic idea, you should think of this to find out the most suitable way of *concrete* implementation of it for your project.

If using your own mapper is not mandatory for you, you can  use some already existing solutions available on market, like for example [Automapper](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper)

Regards.

Comment: This is what I was leaning towards too. Can't use external libraries on this one.

Comment: You can use unique abstract SetMap property that runs an overriden concrete mapper implementation.

Comment: Yes, I think I am goig for this. Now implementing a mapping mechanism that follows the strategy pattern. This way I would look in the strategy repository for any mapping. Also I can extend it quite easily.

Answer (score 1):

If the object is ICLoneable you can leverage that, you can easily check if it is and rely on the implementation. For object that are not ICloneable  [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78536/cloning-objects-in-c) might help you along.

Gert-Jan

Comment: I like the ICloneable approach (Image implements it and would definitely work) and definitely the thread you mentioned is of great help. I am not to keen on relying on ICloneable for the problems that that may hide (cloning/deepcloning etc). +1 anyway